# Print different elements in java

Tags: java, printing

I'm new to Java and I'm not sure how to print these elements in the code. I tried the following but it doesn't work. The error that it gives me basically says(google translate):
Symbol: method print (int, long, long, long, long, long, long)
Location: class java.io.PrintStream
Can someone help? Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SearchComparison{


  public static void main(String[] args){
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
ArrayUtilities utilities = new ArrayUtilities();

int target = -1;
for(int n = 10; n< 10000000; n *= 2){
    watch.start();
    int[] array1 = new int[n];
      array1 = generateRandom(n);
    watch.stop();    
long timeGenerateRandom = watch.getTimeMicro();

watch.start();
utilities.linearSearch(array1, target);
watch.stop();
long timeLinearSearch = watch.getTimeMicro();

watch.start();
utilities.copy(array1);
watch.stop();
long timeCopy = watch.getTimeMicro();

watch.start();
Arrays.sort(utilities.copy(array1));
watch.stop();
long timeLibrary = watch.getTimeMicro();

watch.start();
utilities.sort(array1);
watch.stop();
long timeSort = watch.getTimeMicro();
if(n> 1000000){
  break;
}

watch.start();
utilities.binarySearch(array1, target);
watch.stop();
  long timeBinarySearch = watch.getTimeMicro();

  **System.out.print(n,timeGenerateRandom,timeLinearSearch,timeCopy,timeSort,timeLibrary,timeBinarySearch);
}**
  }

public static int[] generateRandom(int n){
  Random r = new Random(1);
int imax = n;
  int[] array = new int[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      array[i] = r.nextInt(imax);
  }
  return array;
}
}
```

Comment: Please take care to indent your program well before posting it here. You're asking for free advice, and so it's not asking too much for us to expect you to put just a little effort into trying to present your code well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
System.out.print(n,timeGenerateRandom,timeLinearSearch,timeCopy,timeSort,
     timeLibrary,timeBinarySearch);
```

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you're trying to use a method that doesn't exist. The print method doesn't take parameters separated by commas as you're trying to use it. In short: you can't make up methods, or try to give an existing method parameters that it has not been designed for.

Solution: use the method as it's intended with correct parameters, actually a correct **single** parameter. Create a String, and then pass it into your print method.

Or maybe you want to use the `System.out.printf(...)` method. If so, you still need to make a format String to feed the variables into.

Comment: as in String s = ""+ n + timeGenerateRandom + timeLinearSearch + timeCopy + timeSort + timeLibrary + timeBinarySearch; ?

Comment: @user2826974: Rather than ask me, please try it out first and see what you get.

Comment: The most important lesson to gain though is 1) to read your compiler error messages critically, for they'll usually tell you exactly what's wrong, and 2) don't make up methods that don't exist.

Comment: @user2826974: you're getting the `toString()` returned from an array, possibly an array of int. If you want to print an array, you'll need a for loop to iterate through it.